# how to rewriterule 3 line to 1 line in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i have a example for question :
I use 3 line for rewrite

```
RewriteRule ^category.html$ index.php?page=category&type=all&page_value=1
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+).html$ index.php?page=category&type=$1&page_value=1
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)/([0-9]+).html$ index.php?page=category&type=$1&page_value=$2
```

Can i rewriteRule in 1 line?

Comment: That would get needlessly complex ...

Answer (score 2):

Kind of - you could do this:

```
RewriteRule ^category(?:(?:/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+))?(?:/([0-9]+))?)?.html index.php?page=category&type=$1&page_value=$2
```

Demo: http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=ea336c72-76e4-5324-863d-ce32c04573c3

BUT - see how for the base category this does not pass values to your query string so

`http://example.com/category.html`

rewrites to

`http://example.com/index.php?page=category&type=&page_value=`

You would therefore need to ensure your parsing script can handle this with default params for `type` and `page_value`.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Hi @APTX - no problem. If this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.